# Add promo message to product page

Tags: product-page, messages

I'd like to add a generic promo message to the product description page (product information/detail page) under a certain brand. Is there any way to do this without extensions or additional code? Thanks.

Eg- All products under XYZ
Should show a promo message - Get a bonus product when you spend $80 or more on products from Brand XYZ

The shipping cart rules etc have been all set-up to implement this, need help with displaying this message across all the qualifying product page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do without touching any files just from admin-panel you can achieve this thing follow below step

1) create one `cms-block` with your promotional banner.

2) create a `widget`  from `cms->widget` .

3) click on `add new widget instance` .

4) select type as `cms static block` and theme as your `yourpackage/yourtheme`

5) add `widget title` and `sort order`

6) click on add layout exception and select display on  `all product type`

7) and select  radio button specific product page

8) you can see product grid and select on which product you want to show banner

9) select `block reference` for where you want to show your banner

10)click on widget option on left hand side and select you static block .

and clear cache and check , and enjoy your day.

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks so much Murtuza. I'll test this out. Is there a way I can just show the offer message (statement) instead of a banner? Preferable, just under the title of the product.

Comment: For showing on your place, you have to create your own block refrence

Comment: statement is static or dynamic data??

Comment: it's a static statement.

Comment: ok No worry's then just create new block refrence and asign static block

Comment: If my answer help you then mark as accepted so other user take benefit from this post